# C# USB Camera Still Capture Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, camera, capture

I can't seem to find how to capture still images on windows 10 with a USB camera using it's max resolution. This should be simple, but WIA in windows 10 doesn't really support still images. Also tried WPD will only return 1 device. I have also tried using Windows.Media.Catpure.MediaCapture and that just randomly freezes. C# DirectShow is odly slow (like 5 seconds). This should be fairly easy. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.